# MacOS keyboard layout not working on linux trough barrier on gnome

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, macos

My problem is the same as this user:[MacOS keyboard layout not working on linux trough barrier(synergy)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685572/macos-keyboard-layout-not-working-on-linux-trough-barriersynergy/741036#741036)

My workspace contains a Kali Linux installed on a DELL Latitude E54670 and a MacOS Monterey 12.6.1 on a MacBook Air of 2015.

The server is the macOS and the client is the Kali, i user SSL and it's works as well for mouse.

My issue is a little bit complicated, when i type `>`, `{`, `[` on my mac it's doesn't work on Kali.

I've tried to solve my problem by changing the keyboard layout into Macintosh on my kali but it doesn't works; i've tried to add

```
keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)
```

to my barrier.conf file and it's work ! but when i add

```
keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)
keystroke(>) = keystroke(>,*)
```

it's broken

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: is it good now ?

Comment: Do you think it adheres to the [question guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? I think the linked one is a very good example how to write a question with sufficient info so that there's a chance of attempting to resolve the issue, and as you can see from the linked question the answer was found. I'd suggest using that question as a template to model your own after. As that question also has an accepted answer, you should clarify why exactly this answer doesn't resolve your situation.